# SqlDataAdapter Affected 0 out of 1 expected records, even though the dataset was changed

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, xamarin.android

Even though there are many different threads on this, I can't really find an answer for my situation.

I am using Xamarin Android and a web service that updates a SQL Server database. When I call the web method once, it works fine. But when the data is updated and sent again I get this error:

> Concurrency Violation: The UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records
>   I have tried finding anything that accepts the changes of the dataset, also tried .getChanges and tried clearing and refilling the dataset, but I keep getting that error

Here is my code for calling the web method

```
async void startUploadCounter()
{
    SQLWebService.SQLWebService DataService2 = new SQLWebService.SQLWebService();

    await Task.Delay(10000);
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Updating", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    DataService2.updateRooms(rooms,employeeID);
    isEdited = false;
}
```

And here is the code of the web method

```
[WebMethod]
public void updateRooms(DataSet rooms, int employeeID)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"Select * from Room Where AssignedEMP = {employeeID}", connection);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        dataAdapter.Update(rooms);

        // rooms.Clear();
        // rooms.GetChanges();
    }
}
```

If how I'm doing is weird, I'm not too fluent with web service things

Edit: I can confirm that the data is correctly sent to webservice, however, the SQL Data Adapter is not able to change the data for some reason

Edit 2: I have checked the Web service, even when it errors out, it still has the correct data but it just doesn't want to work.

Comment: I think the issue may be that the dataAdapter has already been used because of the select passed into the constructor. Does the room data you've passed in already have AssignedEMP set to employeeID. If so, then you just need to do the update.

Comment: @CurtisShipley, AssignedEMP does have a value already before the program starts, so how would I go to just setting the update command? From what I thought before, when you set the select command in the constructor, it checks between the two datasets and checks each row to see whats different.

Also I would like to thank you for your help on the other issue, it does still exist so I am kinda working blind and trying to fix that issue too, but I'm pretty sure this is the error I am getting.

Comment: I finally got it working to print the error (in the event viewer, but it works, so I'm not complaining) I can confirm that it is still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

So after coming back to the issue. I have done two things. However, I believe this is the one that works

Option 1

If you set the command builder to overwrite changes, it allowed mine to work

```
SqlCommandBuilder.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges
```

Option 2

However, I have also disposed of the command builder and data adapter by doing

```
    dataAdapter.Dispose();
    commandBuilder.Dispose();
    rooms.AcceptChanges();
```